# Convert lat-long to geom using nodejs pg-promise?

Tags: postgis, knn

I have a DB that is used as a read only postgis DB. I also have an input of lat & long to search within my db(in which obviously the points are saved in geom type - using nodejs pg-promise if it matters, but i guess it doesnt as i only need to use the correct sql query)

is there a way of easily requesting the closest node from my db to the input in the form of lat & long?

Comment: read through the [tag:knn] tag to get familiar with the PostGIS concept of *(K) Nearest Neighbor* searches; [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/332059/93656) answer has an example at the bottom with the syntax you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using example from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332047/st-distance-does-not-give-nearest-node/332059#332059)...

Your input example:

```
const place = {
    lng: -122.2652671,
    lat: 47.30995661
};
```

Create a point converter, using [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting):

```
const asPoint = p => ({
    toPostgres: () => pgp.as.format('ST_MakePoint(${lng}, ${lat})', p),
    rawType: true
});
```

Executing the query:

```
await db.oneOrNone(`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY
            ST_StartPoint(geom) <-> ST_SetSRID($1, $2) LIMIT 1;`, [asPoint(place), 4326]);
```