# Shortest road route calculation on OpenLayers GeoDjango

Tags: openlayers, pgrouting, shortest-path

I have created a web based GIS application using Django, Mapnik, Mapproxy, OpenLayers 6. Now I need to develop a shortest path(road distance) between two points selected by the user.  What is the best solution for the development? I have installed PostgreSQL and created a network topology by added two columns namely source and target then executed the select query with function `pgr_createTopology`.

I am using SRID 32643 and data in UTM format. Then to find route between two point I have executed the below query:

```
SELECT seq, node, edge, cost as cost, agg_cost, ST_AsText(the_geom)
FROM pgr_dijkstra( 'SELECT gid as id, source, target, st_length(the_geom) as cost FROM
gistrack_roads', (
    SELECT source
    FROM gistrack_roads
    ORDER BY ST_Distance(
                    ST_StartPoint(the_geom),
                    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(715511.9, 938165.3), 32643)
                ) ASC
            LIMIT 1
        ), (
            SELECT source
            FROM gistrack_roads
            ORDER BY ST_Distance(
                    ST_StartPoint(the_geom),
                    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(717022.4, 938451.4), 32643)
                ) ASC
            LIMIT 1
        )
    ) as pt
    JOIN gistrack_roads rd ON pt.edge = rd.gid;
```

but not getting the correct result.Getting empty records.

I have followed the  tutorial
https://blog.daftcode.pl/find-your-way-with-the-power-of-postgis-pgrouting-66d620ef201b

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain an indication of what a "correct result" would contain, what you actually received, and how what you did receive did not meet expectations. "Best" questions are vulnerable to closure as being *opinion-based* and questions with multiple quesion marks are vulnerable to not being sufficienly *focused*.

Comment: [Better use](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/332059/93656) the GIST *(K)NN* operator [`<->`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) to find the closest point.